Keyboard is bouncing when .onSubmit is executed (@FocusState)
I have the following simplified code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var items: [String] = ["Item1", "Item2"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
                TextField("Add item", text: $text)
                    .focused($isFocused)
                    .onSubmit {
                        items.append(text)
                        text = ""
                        isFocused = true
                    }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

The problem I am encountering is the keyboard which is bouncing slightly when pressing submit. I want the keyboard to stay active instead.

VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            
            HStack { // Use an HStack to contain the TextField
                TextField("Add item", text: $text)
                    .focused($isFocused)
                    .keyboardType(.default)
                
                Button(action: { // Use a Button for submission
                    if !text.isEmpty {
                        items.append(text)
                        text = ""
                        // Keep focus on the TextField
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            isFocused = true
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill") 
                }
                .disabled(text.isEmpty) // Disable button when text is empty
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain) 
    }
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            isFocused = true
        }
    }

You can use add button to add item in the list.Because
The "bouncing" keyboard you're seeing is likely due to the List redrawing itself after you append a new item. The focus shifts briefly as the List updates, causing the keyboard to momentarily dismiss and reappear.

I appreciate your answer, but this is not the solution I am looking for. Instead I am looking for this by pressing the submit button... I know it should be possible.
